# how to change java port in linux server

Tags: java, openfire

I installed openfire in my server and it uses port 9125 but yesterday a problem was occured and now i can't access admin console.

I Tried to access with default openfire port 9090 and i can access but it shows me installation page!

i already installed the Openfire and i tried stop and start again it's services. but nothing fixed! :(

please if u know help me. with netstat comment in putty i see the 9090 port used by java.

how can i change this to another port?

Comment: Have a look at the Openfire documentation.

Comment: I am not sure if Java used some Port it would be RMI  ?

Comment: A quick search for "Openfire change port", revealed this on the first page: http://geekinlinux.blogspot.de/2012/08/how-to-change-default-port-9090-for.html - is this what you're after?

Comment: Take a look to http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jimc/documents/xmpp-1307/xmpp-openfire-1307.html

Comment: i check the server using netstat and i see the 9090 port is using by java and now i can access my openfire via this port i changed this port when i installed openfire many mounths ago and now it's changed to 9090 autimatically! and in  9090 it redfirect me to installation!

Comment: @Thomas i see the link u give me but this way is not working!